# Java: Google App Engine "HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL" error

Tags: java, google-app-engine, post

I just started playing with Google App Engine and Java. I've used Servlets in the past and I understand how they work. I'm trying to make a servlet to `POST` to, but it's not going over very well.

Here's my Servlet:

```
public class CreateUser extends HttpServlet
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Here's what I get when I post to this from a form:

```
HTTP ERROR 405
Problem accessing /user/create. Reason:
HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL
```

I don't understand why I'm getting this when I clearly have implemented doPost. I've double and triple checked the DD (web.xml) file to make sure I have the url mappings correct. I can't find anything online specifically about this. I figure I am over looking something quite simple.

Here's my web.xml:

```
<web-app...>
    ...
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>CreateUser</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.joelj.music.api.CreateUser</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Index</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/user/create</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Thanks.

Comment: I don't see the annotation for servlet registration, so I assume it's in web.xml. Could you post web.xml for us?

Comment: Yeah, I'll get that up as soon as I can. I don't have access to the code right at the moment though. I'll get it up in a couple hours. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, I updated the code. I have removed that entry in web.xml just to see if the error changes and it changes to `404 File Not Found`. So it's going to that servlet, it just doesn't see my `doPost`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I feel really stupid. After looking at the code I just posted I realized that the entry was pointed to Index. I can't believe I over looked it so many times.